# Use the output of a javascript program on a webpage to a facebook share

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, web-deployment

I apologize I am completely new to Javascript, web dev, and facebook.  I've read https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart and don't know where to even start.

I have a javascript calculator and want users to be able to post their results to facebook.  Example:  "I got 500,000 people and 5%".  Is there a way to grab the result from javascript and pipe it to a facebook post?  If I have variables ageValue and PercentValue can I use them as output?

Thanks.

My calculator for reference:
http://www.iwonderifyouareoutthere.com/woman.html

Comment: try the feed dialog: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog

Comment: btw, you can NOT use the outcome as a message, because prefilling the message is not allowed. you must read the platform policy before creating any app.

Answer (score 0):

The following is a simple example to share something to facebook via javascript. After getting an appid and corresponding api version you can use this for sharing/posting to Facebook

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html>
     <head>
     <script src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js"></script>
     </head>
     <body>
     <p id="demo">Facebook Share</p>
     <button onclick="myFunction()">Share</button>

     <script>
     FB.init({
     appId: appid,
     status: true,
     cookie: true,
     xfbml: true,
     version: version
     });
     function myFunction(){  
         FB.ui({
             method: 'feed',
             name: 'hi',
             link: 'www.google.com',
             picture: 'pictureurl',
             caption: 'any caption ',
             description:'any description'
             });
           }
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thank you.  Is there a way to get the data from the javascript app?